# React Navigation V5: How to navigate to particular tab of BottomTabNavigator (react navigation version 5)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have code something like this:

```
 <Stack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
        <Stack.Screen name="WelcomeScreen" component={WelcomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
        <Stack.Screen name="OnboardingSummary" component={OnboardingSummary} />  
        <Stack.Screen name="BottomTabs" component={BottomTabs} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Player" component={Player} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Here BottomTabs is BottomTab **BottomTabNavigator**

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    <Tab.Navigator
        tabBar={props => <VialmaTabs {...props} />}
    >
        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={profileStack} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeStack} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
```

Home stack has 2 screens **UserList, UserDetails**

```
function HomeStack() {
return (
    <RadioStack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
        <RadioStack.Screen name="UserList" component={UserList} />
        <RadioStack.Screen name="UserDetails" component={UserDetails} />
    </RadioStack.Navigator>
);
```

}

I am on Player Screen at the moment and I want to redirect UserDetails Screen(it will skip bottom tabs and UseList.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried props.navigation.navigate({routeName:"UserDetails"})?

Comment: @giotskhada didn't work. trying the below solution but not able to get it right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution for the above problem and I would like to share it with you as well.

```
import { StackActions, CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('BottomTabs', {
            screen: 'Home', 
                params: {
                         screen: 'UserDetails',
                         params: {
                           [....PARAMS],
                         }
                }
        }));
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: i need the same thing for react-navigation version 4, does anyone know how ?